# Moving Data to Specific Columns and rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns of data in my excel sheet:

```
    Month: 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, etc.
    Day: 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 6, 1, 2, 3, etc.
```

What I would like to do is set up the months in additional columns.  Then match that month with the month's day in each row.  I'd like to write a sub routine for this in VBA so that with any set of data (month and day) I can do the iteration.  So my range would be something like A1:A.... So from the example above it would look something like this:

```
    January February March April May June July August ....
                             2    6    1
                             2         2
                             2         3
                             3
                             4
```

I've played around with some If statements, but I am getting too many variables and think I am making it more complicated then I need to.

Edits:

```
    j = 10
    k = 2
    m = 11
    v = 2
    u = 13
    LastRow_0 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow_0
    If Cells(i, j) = 4 Then
        Cells(v, u) = Cells(k, m)
            Else: Cells(v, u) = ""
                k = k + 1
                v = v + 1

    End If
    Next i
```

This is what I have.  It is not liking the ".Rows.Count" syntax.  Months are j and days are m.  u is the month of April in column # u (13).  I would then copy and paste this code twelve times to get all of the months.  v and k are changing by 1 to go through all the rows until i runs out.  Basically until Null.

Edits 2:

```
    'January
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form Date")
        LR1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LR1
        If Cells(i, 10) = 1 Then
            Cells(i, 13) = Cells(i, 11)
                Else: Cells(i, 13) = ""

        End If
    Next i
    End With
    '--------------------------------------------------------
    'Febuary
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form Date")
        LR2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LR2
        If Cells(i, 10) = 2 Then
            Cells(i, 14) = Cells(i, 11)
                Else: Cells(i, 14) = ""

        End If
    Next i
    End With
    '---------------------------------------------------------
    'March
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Form Date")
        LR3 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LR3
        If Cells(i, 10) = 3 Then
            Cells(i, 15) = Cells(i, 11)
                Else: Cells(i, 15) = ""

        End If
    Next i
    End With
```

I gave it some more thought and change a couple of things to exclude some variables.  Ended up not needing them.  I would like a smaller code of what I have here, so it takes less time to run and I don't need 12 of these.

Comment: Can you share the code you have already written so we can see where you need help..

Comment: You can use **arrays** instead of many variables, that should make it short and understandable. Also share the code that you have tried so far, so that we can see what is that you are doing wrong.

Comment: see edits above in original post.